# if element contains text

Tags: jquery

I just want to check if an element contains text and run code accordingly. Something like this...

```
if ($('#MTD-Head').text:contains("(w/ DOTCOM)"))
{
    $('#MTD-Head').text("MONTH TO DATE (w/o DOTCOM)");
}
else 
{
    $('#MTD-Head').text("MONTH TO DATE (w/ DOTCOM)");         
}
```

What is the proper syntax to achieve this?

Comment: Why couldn't you read the DOC??? You already know `:contains` obviously...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($('#MTD-Head:contains("(w/ DOTCOM)")').length > 0) {
    // Do something
}
else {
    // Do something else
}
```